# C# create Filewatcher object in loop

Tags: c#, oop

I am creating a `Filewatcher` in the loop below. I would like to know if there are any performance or reference issues, since my reference variable is the same in the loop?

```
foreach (var dir in dirsToWatch)
{
    **var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dir);**
    watcher.Filter = filter;
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(onChange);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(onChange);
}
```

Comment: No? Based on what you have, you're _forced_ to do it the way you're doing it. You can't create the `watcher` variable without a reference to `dir`. Each loop iteration will make its own `watcher` variable, but you can't use `watcher` outside the loop. Are you thinking about Disposing the object?

Comment: thx yes thinking of disposing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what the end goal of your code is, but if you want to use the `watcher` objects after the loop is done, then you'll need to save their instances in a collection outside of the loop. Otherwise you'll have no reference to them and they'll just get garbage-collected.

For example:

```
var watchers = new List<FileSystemWatcher>();

foreach (var dir in dirsToWatch)
{
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dir) {Filter = filter};
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(onChange);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(onChange);
    watchers.Add(watcher);
}

// Do something with watchers here

// Dispose of watchers when done
watchers.ForEach(watcher => watcher.Dispose());
```